# How to fix “swift package generate-xcodeproj” results in manifest parse error?

Tags: ios, swift, package

I'm new to Swift and the Package Manager. I'm following a tutorial that generates the Xcode project file, but I get errors when I run "swift package generate-xcodeproj" (or "swift package update" for that matter). Below is the output.

It looks like it doesn't recognise the 'uuid_string_t' type in hfs_format.h header file.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm using Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5 on macOS 10.14.4. My Xcode Command Line Tools setting under the Location Preferences tab is set to 10.2.

```
/Users/rayscott/Developer/Source/Swift/TCPClient: error: manifest parse error(s):
:353:9: note: in file included from :353:
#import "hfs/hfs_format.h"
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/hfs/hfs_format.h:794:2: error: unknown type name 'uuid_string_t'
uuid_string_t ext_jnl_uuid;
^
:353:9: note: in file included from :353:
#import "hfs/hfs_format.h"
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/hfs/hfs_format.h:796:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'uuid_string_t'; did you mean 'uuid_variant'?
char reserved[JIB_RESERVED_SIZE];
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/hfs/hfs_format.h:787:61: note: expanded from macro 'JIB_RESERVED_SIZE'
#define JIB_RESERVED_SIZE ((32*sizeof(u_int32_t)) - sizeof(uuid_string_t) - 48)
^
/usr/local/include/uuid/uuid.h:98:5: note: 'uuid_variant' declared here
int uuid_variant(const uuid_t uu);
^
:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing Xcode 10.2 and macOS 10.14.4. Solution for me was to run the following commands in Terminal:

1. `brew doctor`, and fix the mentioned issues
2. `sudo xcode-select --reset`

After executing these steps I did a reboot, and build started to work again.